# When downloading multiple files, should you give many options

Tags: web, dialog, download

I'm showing every owner of spots at a radio station, a list of all commercials he has available to download. Spots can be downloaded one at a time by clicking on a spot's code, where the browser's built in downloader fires off.

To download many spots at once, there is a selection check box to the left of the spots code where (by default), all spots that the guy hasn't got yet are checked. Above this list are buttons [Download]  [JavaDownloader] [Bulk Download] and [FTP]. Then there are boxes for a path to download to, defaulting to c:\downloads\ or whatever they picked last time.

This is meant to be used by minimum wage guys on the night shift at WKRP etc.

This is obviously very confusing. Any suggestions as to how to phrase this or do a pulldown or something nice?

(I wish I could attach a screen shot as to how busy this screen is.)

Comment: Someone edit this post, if you understood what he's asking!

Comment: If you put your screenshot on some image sharing site and post the link here, I am sure that someone with enough reputation will be kind enough to add it to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Make it as easy as possible for the user.  If possible, avoid them having to click 20 times.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fL723r.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

The archive links should update according to the audio format the user selected.  (This is a little bit of Javascript.)

Comment: I think the two tasks should be numbered 1 and 2.  That may help to show the user it is a process, rather than two different options!